# F# Parse command line arguments, expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point ; or ;;

Tags: f#, arguments, pattern-matching

I have a basic F# CLI that mimics F# touch command , my program takes a file name , creates the file if it exists or updates access time if it doesn't.

Core functionality is done, but it is supposed to mimic Linux' command Touch in terms of syntax. The syntax should be 'touch file1.text' for file creation or 'touch --version' for a message I want to print when option is given.

My core problems are:-
1. Having my code follow Linux' syntax -

Current - >>>Test.text = File created.

Expected - >>> touch test.txt or

touch --version = File created or touch command information printed.

2. Taking --version and --help or similar valid input and printed the corresponding information.

Current result

> test.txt // File created
>   0 //

Expected

> touch test.text //file created
>   0 //
>   or
>   Expected
>   touch --version / touch --help
>   /* Touch information
>   Touch information
>   Touch information
>   Touch information*/

Tried using the Argu library but seems out of my current scope, currently attempting with argument parser module.

````
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

open System
open System.IO
open System.Text

type filename = String


let touch path =
   //Console.ReadLine()
    if File.Exists path
    then File.SetLastWriteTime(path, DateTime.Now) 
    else 
         if not(File.Exists path)
         then File.WriteAllText(path, " ")
         Console.ReadKey()|>ignore





[<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn "Touch Command - Built using F#"
        printfn "Please enter the file you want to touch"
        if argv |> Array.contains "Help " then 
               printfn "Display help here"
               exit(0)
               printfn "Version information"
               exit(0)
        for filename in argv do
            touch(filename)
        0    
        // return an integer exit code



     ```

Current result 
> test.txt // File created
> 0 // internal 

Expected
>touch test.text //file created
>0 //internal

or
Expected
>touch --version / touch --help
>/* Touch information
Touch information
Touch information
Touch information*/

No current errors
When argu library attempted, to many errors to bring to solution board.
````

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is an array of strings, so the simplest way to tell if `--help` or `--version` is in that array is to use the `Array.contains` function:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Argv: %A" argv  // Helpful in debugging, remove in final version
    if argv |> Array.contains "--help" then
        printfn "Display help here"
        exit(0)
    if argv |> Array.contains "--version" then
        printfn "Version information"
        exit(0)
    for filename in argv do
        touch(filename)
```

Note that this example is assuming that you rewrite your `touch` function to take a `filename` parameter instead of reading the filename from the console via `Console.ReadLine`.

Also note that after an attribute like `[<EntryPoint>]`, there's no need to add a second level of indentation. The attribute should be indented at the same level as the `let` declaration that it's modifying. So you should write your `let main argv =` line at the top level of your module (i.e., with zero indentation).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when i attempt to implement this, i receive an error on Array.contains ' This expression was expected to have type 'string[]' but here has type ''a[]->bool'. It looks like exactly what I need, the only thing is for the program to match specs it must take the path from the user in console.

Comment: @user12033340 - How are you calling `Array.contains`? Based on the error you mentioned, I think you have a syntax mistake somewhere but it's hard to guess what it is. Also, sometimes it helps to specify the type of `argv` in the `main` function, e.g. instead of `let main argv =` sometimes it's better to write `let main (argv : string[]) =`. The reason why has to do with internals of how the F# compiler works, and it's not worth worrying about at your current level of F# understanding. But you might try making that change and seeing if that helps. If it doesn't, show me the line that fails.

Comment: @user12033340 - Also, when you say "for the program to match specs it must take the path from the user in console" - what specs? Is this for an assignment where you are given specs to match? Because if the specs you're going for are replication how the Linux `touch` command works, it doesn't take the path from the user in the *console*, it takes it in the *command parameters*, which in F# are passed in as the `argv` array. (Those parameters are *typed* on the console, yes, but don't be confused by the name `Console.ReadLine`: that is not how the Linux `touch` command takes its parameters).

Comment: I think your right on the money again, the point you made about the input being a console parameter rather then a read line has explained  a lot. Yes i am trying to replicate the linux touch command , if thats the case I would much prefer to do it your way, how do I re code tap so that it takes it from the user as a parameter instead of a console.readline?

Comment: I'll try to open another question directed towards how to convert my readline into argv parameters. @rmunn

Comment: It's really very simple: my example has half the work done for you already. Then you just change `let touch() =` into `let touch path =` and remove the `let path = Console.ReadLine()` line. Done. What this has done is to make the `touch` function have one parameter called `path`, which the rest of the function will use. And you'll notice that the `main` function goes through `argv` one item at a time, passing each string in `argv` into the `touch` function. So there you go: argv gest turned into function parameters to `touch`.

Comment: And since you're asking basic questions like this, it's obvious that you need to work through an F# tutorial, which will teach you about function parameters and other basic parts of F# syntax. In one of your earlier questions, which was deleted around the time you switched user accounts, I recommended https://github.com/ChrisMarinos/FSharpKoans to you. I'll repeat that recommendation here. You'll learn WAY more from going through those exercises than you will by asking questions here on Stack Overflow -- at least for now.

Comment: Turns out I still had that deleted question open in another tab, so I can recreate my original comment to you. What I said earlier (which I still recommend) was: It seems to me that you're trying to bite off more than you can (yet) chew. I suggest starting with http://github.com/ChrisMarinos/FSharpKoans to learn F# syntax in a more guided way. Then try the exercises at http://exercism.io/tracks/fsharp first, as they start with simple tasks and slowly build up to more complex things. After you run through those two learning tools, you may be able to answer your own question!

Comment: Thanks, currently reading through  the koan documents, I've recieved one final error in [<entrypoint>] for file name in argv do touch (filename) - This expression was expected to have type 'int' but here has type 'unit', why does the expression expect an int?

Comment: Ah. The thing expecting an int is the `main` function, which is expected to return an int as the exit code of your program. To return a value from main, simply make it the last line of the function, as in the `0 // return an exit code` line from your original example. Just keep that `0` as the last line of your `main` function (do NOT put it inside the for loop, but indent it as you indent the rest of the code in `main`) and you'll fix that compiler error.

Comment: @user12033340 - You appear to be trying to ask a new question with the edit you made to this one, but I can't make heads or tails of what you're saying. Also, why did you remove the `if argv |> Array.contains "--version"` line? The way your code is currently written in the question, the `printfn "Version information"` line will never run, because it will exit before it gets to that point.